# Git commit a directory while not in the git path

Tags: git

Is there a way to specify the directory to commit/stash from the command line?

My use-case is that I want to put a `git commit -am "some default message"` as a command in `postdeactivate` script in `virtualenvwrapper`. That way it does a commit when I `deactivate` my environment. I don't want to just put the command in the script as-is because I may have changed directories and it could either fail (not terrible) or commit the wrong repo (very annoying).

I guess I could have the script `cd` to the project directory first, but it seems like there should be a cleaner way.

Comment: `cd` into it. It’s the clearest way to do it. You can use `pushd` a `popd` though to make it a bit more temporary.

Comment: I knew it had to be on the internet somewhere I just couldn't find the right google keywords. Should have used `absolute path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git --git-dir=the/local/repo/.git --work-tree=the/local/repo commit
```

[Git Status From Outside of the Working Directory](http://bubblefoundry.com/blog/2011/02/git-status-from-outside-of-the-working-directory)